# How to convert a host Windows 8 into guest?

Tags: windows-8, virtualbox

I have Windows 8 running as host along side Ubuntu on my laptop, I want to convert my Windows 8 installation into a virtual machine so that I can get rid of Windows as a host and just run it as a guest OS using VirtualBox. What tool do I use to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in the below link:

[Vbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Migrate_Windows)

Also you can follow the quick steps:

Windows is pretty easy to clone to virtual machine with Microsoft tool called [Disk2vhd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx). You can do it on a running Windows system as I did with my Windows 2008 server.

1. download Disk2vhd and extract it to some folder.
2. Start the software and choose which partition you want to clone.
   3 Wait for the cloning to finish, in my case this took about 50 minutes
3. Copy the resulting .vhd file to your virtual machine host.
4. Start your virtual machine software and make a new VM.
5. Mount the disk on the VM you just made and boot.
6. If everything went right you should now have a clone of your Windows system running in a VM
   If you are migrating a Windows installation to VirtualBox you might want to check out the how-to on on the VirtualBox website

Comment: I have used that tool, and when I tried to boot it using Virtualbox, a message appeared saying "grub rescue"!